# Changing the default login in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel and php.
I use in my project Laravel 6.

I have this migrations:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

How to change Laravel's default login so that it allows the login of a user who has enable = 1 (enable = 0 - we do not allow, similar to those with an incorrect password)

Comment: [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users), under "Specifying Additional Conditions".

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#authenticating-users) on Manually Authenticating Users, you can use this code to authenticate users with `enabled` field set to `true` only.

```php
$email = $request->input('email');
$password = $request->input('password');

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'enabled' => 1])) {
   // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I mage this: https://pastebin.com/QtWPgrc7 - and this code always login (when I have enable = 0 or enable =1)

Comment: @traffske It's probably because type of enabled is char, Try changing it boolean or integer and see if it works.